TestContainers and microservices with Spring Boot
I have 2 microservices:
Service A has an endpoint to create Article entities. This entity has a property Supplier among others. When creating an Article, the corresponding method calls (using Feign) an endpoint from Service B which returns the Supplier if it exists.
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "article")
public class ArticleDAO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SupplierDAO supplier;
}

Code to create an Article:
@Override
    public Article createArticle(final Article article, final String usuario) {
        final List<ArticleDAO> articleDAOS;
        
        if(this.suppliersFeignClient.getSupplier(article.getSupplier().getId().getBody() == null)
                // do something
        this.checkArticleDontExistByName(article);
        articles.forEach(article -> article.setUser(usuario));
        articleDAOS = this.modelMapper.map(articles, new TypeToken<List<ArticleDAO>>(){}.getType());
        this.articleRepository.saveAll(articleDAOS);
        return this.modelMapper.map(articleDAOS, new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){}.getType());
    }

Here, I am not finding a way to connect Service A with Service B whith both running a database for integration tests since both use mysql. I would need Service A to run a mysql container using TestContainers and also to run Service B which also needs its own mysql container.
I am learning about Integration Tests with microservices and on my journey I found the TestContainers library which I managed to write tests using a mysql image but without having interaction with other microservices. Now that I have 2 microservices I have no idea at all about how to write the tests for this since Service B also uses mysql.
Can anyone give me any guidance on how to achieve this? Is TestContainers not good for integration tests when there's more than one service?
I know this question could be a bit tangly, I will add more info or code if needed but so far I just have this in my integration test which works perfectly if I comment this.suppliersFeignClient.getSupplier(article.getSupplier().getId().getBody() == null:
    @ServiceConnection
    @Container
    private static final MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>(ContainersConstants.MYSQL_CONTAINER_TAG);
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ArticlesService articlesService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        mySQLContainer.start();
    }



    @AfterAll
        static void afterAll() {
            mySQLContainer.stop();
        }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Create articles /articles")
    void WHEN_calling_create_articles_THEN_status_is_200() {
        final List<ArticleDTO> articleDTOS = Instancio.ofList(ArticleDTO.class).size(3)
                .ignore(field(ArticleDTO::getId))
                .ignore(field(ArticleDTO::getCategory))
                .ignore(field(ArticleDTO::getSupplier))
                .create();
        final CreateArticlesRequest createArticlesRequest = CreateArticlesRequest.builder()
                .articles(articleDTOS)
                .user(Instancio.create(String.class))
                .build();
        final ResponseEntity<CreateArticlesResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(restTemplate.getRootUri() + URIConstants.ARTICLES_URI,
                HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(createArticlesRequest), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
        final List<ArticleDTO> articles = Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getArticles();

        articles.forEach(article -> article.setId(null));

        assertEquals(articles.size(), articleDTOS.size() , "articles.size() should be " + articleDTOS.size());
        assertTrue(articles.containsAll(articleDTOS), "articles should contain the same elements as articulosDTOS");
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode(), "Status Code should be " + HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Thanks

If you want to make each service to have its own database and you are running both of them on the same machine, you want to use different port for each container.
And to do the integration test you will want to provide the host and the port of the other service and send the request to it, In your code you are sending the request to the same service that run the test.
